# Algorithms for handling misaligned resolution values of images/videos

Tags: image-processing

I know many algorithms to improve image quality. But now I am thinking about an apparently much simpler problem: how to display image when the pixels are not properly aligned with the screen's resolution?

For instance, when playing a 1080p video on a 1440p screen, the computer has to work out how to assign colour and brightness of those physical pixels, as there is no simple correspondence to the original 1080p pixels in the video file. Along the way, we can also do some super-resolution (but this is not necessary).

Or: play a high-resolution video on a small window.

Surely, linear interpolation or any other simple method like that is not going to have very good results. There should be a mathematically elegant and more subtle way of handling these scenarios. What algorithms are used in practice? Could anyone provide a reference including the relevant equations?

[There is a related but different post here.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/73798)

Comment: not quite sure, but you're simply asking about *image scaling*  / *resampling* algorithms, right?